# Does the PDFTron support get image from api in react native?

Tags: react-native, pdftron, react-native-pdf

is there a way to select image data from API as signature then paste it in pdf instead of selecting image from gallery/photo/camera in react-native-pdftron  ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. Instead of the user selecting the image itself, you want to choose the image for the user automatically through an API and avoiding extra user steps? Screenshots would help a lot.